# c reporting which signal terminated a child

Tags: c, signals, fork

I've been working on a shell pretty extensively, and now I'm trying to upgrade this code to report when a child has been terminated by a signal (other than SIGINT).
I'm also trying to report a "core dump" if one happened in parenthesis (similar to bash).

```
   ...

   if(test == -1){ 
      cpid = fork();
      if(cpid < 0){
         //Fork wasn't successful 
         perror("fork");
         free(argList);
         return -1;
      }

      if(cpid == 0){
         //We are the child!
         close(pipefd[0]);
         dup2(pipefd[1], 1);

         execvp(args[0], args);         
         //execvp returned, wasn't successful
         perror("exec");
         fclose(stdin);  
         exit(127);
      }
      close(pipefd[1]);

      //Have the parent wait for child to complete, if flags allow 
      if(strcmp(flags, "NOWAIT") != 0){

         if(wait (&status) < 0){
            //Wait wasn't successful
            perror("wait");
         }
         else{


////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        //report if a child has been terminated by a signal other than SIGINT
        if((WIFSTOPPED(status) && (WSTOPSIG(status) != SIGINT))){

           printf("child terminated by signal [%d]\n", WSTOPSIG(status));

           if(WCOREDUMP(status)){
              printf("core dumped\n");
           }
        }
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

           free(argList);
           //since no child is running, return 0
           return 0;
         }
      }
      else{
         //if a child is running, return the child's pid
         return cpid;
      } 
   }

   ...
```

I'm not really sure how to proceed with this. This is my first time working this extensively with the fork() command and my knowledge of the parent-child relationship is pretty shoddy, to tell the truth. I've searched for answers and the closest I've gotten is that SIGCHLD handles this sort of thing, but I need to be able to print out a specific number. something like:

`printf("child terminated (%d)\n", 15 + signal);`

*edit**
I put what I think to be the correct implementation of what I want into the code, surrounded by ////////

Comment: You will need to write a "signal handler" that handles "SIGCHLD"... (in Unix/Linux see: man sigaction  or man signal).  Be sure to pay attention to caveats about what you can do, or functions you cannot call in your signal handler.

Comment: Avoid SIGCHLD if you can help it -- it's perniciously difficult to use, in my experience.  As long as you're doing something straightforward, one of the `wait` functions should be fine.  The `status` value you get back should tell you everything you need to know: if I remember correctly, its low-order byte gives you the signal that killed the process (if any) and the bit that tells you if it dumped core, and the next byte is the process's exit status (`main's return value).  `man 2 wait` should give you the details.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You collect the status of the child with your chosen variant of `wait()` or [`waitpid()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/waitpid.html) — or on BSD `wait3()` or `wait4()` if you like — and then analyze the status.

POSIX provides:

- `WIFEXITED(status)` — returns true if the program exited under control.
- `WEXITSTATUS(status)` — returns the exit status (0..255).
- `WIFSIGNALED(status)` — returns true if the program exited because of a signal.
- `WTERMSIG(status)` — returns the terminating signal.
- `WIFSTOPPED(status)` — if the child was stopped by a signal.
- `WSTOPSIG(status)` — the signal that stopped the child.
- `WIFCONTINUED(status)` — if the child has continued since a stop signal.

POSIX does not define, but many Unix-based implementations provide:

- `WCOREDUMP(status)` — returns true if a core was dumped.

Comment: That helped a lot, thank you. I looked at your answer and the comments on my post, and read the manual pages on wait more thoroughly. I put what I believe to work into my code so that others can see it.